# Datagridview Index was out of range

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing a simple datagridview update function

I have 2 forms. 1 for datagridview and another for the textboxes for update purpose.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The error was thrown at this code

```
Form1.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value = txtName.Text
```

But in Form1 i have a code that takes the current data in datagridview and it works perfectly.

```
Dim name As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString
Form2.txtName.Text = name
```

Comment: That first code snippet is referring to the default instance of `Form1`. My guess is that the instance of `Form1` that you're looking at is not the default instance, therefore you're referring to a different `Form1` instance in which no rows are selected.  This is why so many experienced developers hate default instances.

Comment: I meant exactly what I said. What did you not understand about the information you found when you Googled "default instance"?